# função em graphics.h

Tags: c, c++

Estou tentando aprender um pouco mais das bibliotecas em C/C++ para fazer mais coisas por isso fui atrás da biblioteca graphics.h e fui atrás do código mais básico que encontrei, que foi:

```c
#include <graphics.h>

int main(){
    int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, errorcode;

    char *str = new char[30];
    strcpy(str, "d:\\tc\\bgi");
    initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode, str);

    arc(200, 200, 0, 130, 50);

    closegraph();

    return 0;
}
```

O que acontece é que o programa compilou, abriu, parou de responder sem executar o que eu pedi e fechou

Comment: "sem executar o que eu pedi" hmmm não terá sido 'executando o que eu pedi tão rápido que nem consegui aperceber-me da execução'? *Experimenta executar o programa em modo 'debug', instrução a instrução.*

Comment: Não, ele realmente não executa, eu usei system("PAUSE"); e ele não chega nem a rodar o comando, depois eu debuguei na mão passando varias linhas como comentário e descobri que o erro está na função initgraph();

Comment: Uma observação: É uma boa prática inicializar as váriaveis. Qual o valor da variavel gmode?

Comment: Eu entendo que é, mas como eu falei, eu só copiei o que o cara fez, para ele funcionou e para mim não.

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, mesmo instalando a `graphics.h` corretamente, o código era compilado e alguns segundos após aparecer, a tela do console parava de responder do nada, descobri que o problema era o arquivo "`libbgi.a`", tente baixar [este](https://github.com/stahta01/windows-games/blob/master/WinBGIm/lib/libbgi.a) e substitui-lo na pasta "`lib`" do compilador.